# Unable to stream in stereo

Tags: agora.io

I am using a 3d mic that works like a charm on the iPhone using 1/8th jack into an adapter. It works great with the camera app so I know the hardware is able to receive the stereo.

However in my agora.io iPhone app I have the following settings:

```
audio.setChannelProfile(.liveBroadcasting)
audio.setAudioProfile(.musicHighQualityStereo, scenario: .showRoom)
```

Is there anything else I need to do for it to work?

Comment: Are you able to get mono input from the microphone? If so, you may want to try to configure the AVAudioSession yourself, and use `setAudioSessionOperationRestriction` to give yourself more control for fine tuning.

Comment: Hi I am able to get mono input form the microphone. In fact, I am able to select it as preferred input and when I enable in ear playback, I hear the audio in stereo.

Comment: Additionally, when I do a "echo test" I hear it on the device in Mono. So clearly, there is an issue somewhere past the "in ear monitoring" to the signal being sent to agora.

Comment: Can you share the exact mic you're using and the exact adapter? And which agora SDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reach Agora Support. The following answer is what I received:

iOS devices does not support stereo audio capture. You would need to use external video source which support stereo audio to do the capture.

I wish this were included in the iOS documentation.

For my use case, a Mac app would be better, so I'm just going to go with that!

Comment: Yes, the hardware works fine in the camera app. Which is consistent with the need for using an external video support for it to work with Agora.